# "ТрАпезная" или "трапЕзная"?

Tags: фонетика

"Тр***а***пезная" или "трап***е***зная"? Чаще слышу "тр***а***пезная", но при этом есть выражение "затрап***е***зный". Как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос.
До недавнего времени словари рекомендовали только первый вариант - тр**а**пеза, и, соответвенно, тр**а**пезная.
Однако сейчас уже встречается указание на возможность двоякого ударения: тр**а**пеза и трап**е**за (Лопатин, например).

Насколько понимаю, этим восстанавливается историческая справедливость, в церковнославянском ударение на второй слог, отсюда, кстати, безвариантное трап**е**зничать.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, ударение в слове "трапезничать" переходит на второй слог из-за более удобного произношения, т.к. слово состоит не из трех, как "трапеза", а из четырех слогов.

Кстати, слово "трапеза", происходящее из греческого, произносится в самом греческом с ударением на первый слог.

Answer (score -1):

В греческом языке слово "стол"произноситься "трапЕзи"(ударение как раз на 2ом слоге),поэтому,если хотите,произносите в том числе по Лопатину.Отсюда - трапЕзничать т.е.столоваться. По-русски удобнее,конечно, говорить "трАпеза".И то и то - правильно.

Comment: Минус, видимо, в связи с затрапезной пунктуацией.